# Scene kit (Swift): Unhide or re-add hidden / removed nodes

Tags: swift, scenekit

I'm trying to create a game in which someone taps a box, which makes it disappear. My problem is with 'restarting' the game and re-adding all previously hidden / removed boxes.

I create a row of boxes like so:

```
func addBoxes() {

    for _ in 0..<5 {

        let sphereGeometry = SCNBox(width: 1, height: 1, length: 1, chamferRadius: 0)
        let sphereNode: SCNNode! = SCNNode(geometry: sphereGeometry)
        sphereNode.position = SCNVector3(x: x, y: y, z: z)

        scnScene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)
}
```

After which I update the position of x, y and z of course.

This all works beautifully, and I hide a tapped box like so:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch = touches.first!
    let location = touch.location(in: scnView)
    let hitResults = scnView.hitTest(location, options: nil)

    if let result = hitResults.first {

        let node = result.node
        node.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

After all boxes are tapped and hidden, the game should simply reset for now, so unhide all boxes:

```
func newGame() {

    // I've tried this and various versions of it, with no success
    for child in scnScene.rootNode.childNodes {

        child.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

However, this gives me:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I've also tried `child.removeFromParentNode()` and then tried to re-add the nodes to the scene, but this throws the same error.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? How can I unhide one or all nodes which are created in the for loop?

Comment: Can you add an exception breakpoint to get the exact line that crashes? I don't see an optional in your code at all. Or is `scnScene` declared as `SCNScene!`?

Comment: @ orangenkopf: yes, it is. It crashes at `scnScene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)`

Comment: `SCNNode(geometry:)` does not return an optional, so you can delete the type `SCNNode` and let the compiler infere the type. But your problem has nothing to do with hiding/ unhiding. Rather you probably have not created your scene when you try to add nodes to it

Comment: Thanks, i tried that and the error indeed no longer occurs! However, why wouldnt the scene be created yet as the nodes do show up the first time when `addBoxes()` is called? After touching a node, I set `isHidden`  for it to `true`, but unhiding it doesnt bring it back. I also tried to remove the tapped node, and when all nodes are gone calling `addBoxes()` again, but this doesnt do anything

Comment: You are right, that does not make sense. I was just not expexting that declaring you `sphereNode` as optional would crash

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue but everything is working fine. Check [this gist](https://gist.github.com/orangenkopf/3977378fa07fd9d330f68b0574ce49ac) for my solution. Please edit your question with additional information if you have missed some details.

Comment: @ orangenkopf this is great! I implemented your code into mine (except for the random position) and this does exactly what I want. Turns out I think I was messing up the positions of the nodes. If you post you respons as answer i'll accept it as the solution : )

Comment: Btw one remaining question: adding the `gestureRecognizer` seems to prevent the default `CameraControl` functions to stop working, like double tap to reset its position. Is that correct?

Comment: Never mind, I set my scene at the wrong view, its working now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hiding and unhiding works fine like this:

```
var targetsToDo: Int = 0
let maximumNumberOfTargets = 5

func loadGame() {
    targetsToDo = maximumNumberOfTargets

    scnScene = SCNScene()
    scnView.scene = scnScene

    for i in 1...maximumNumberOfTargets {
        let box = SCNBox(width: 1, height: 1, length: 1, chamferRadius: 0.1)
        let node = SCNNode(geometry: box)
        node.name = "Box \(i)"
        scnScene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
        node.position = getRandomPosition()
    }
}

@objc func handleTouch(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let point = recognizer.location(in: view)
    print("Touch at \(NSStringFromCGPoint(point))")
    if let node = scnView.hitTest(point).first?.node {
        print(node.name ?? "")
        node.isHidden = true
        targetsToDo -= 1

        if targetsToDo == 0 {
            resetGame()
        }
    }
}

func resetGame() {
    targetsToDo = maximumNumberOfTargets

    for child in scnScene.rootNode.childNodes {
        child.isHidden = false
        child.position = getRandomPosition()
    }
}
```

A complete, working playground can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/orangenkopf/3977378fa07fd9d330f68b0574ce49ac).